# Theme dependent drawables in compose

Tags: android-studio, themes, drawable, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating a project to compose and I came across this drawable that changes its colors based on the theme

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="70dp"
android:height="70dp"
android:viewportWidth="70"
android:viewportHeight="70">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/color_surface"
    android:pathData="M35,35m-35,0a35,35 0,1 1,70 0a35,35 0,1 1,-70 0" />
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/sync_profile_fill"
    android:pathData="M35,35m-35,0a35,35 0,1 1,70 0a35,35 0,1 1,-70 0" />
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/transparent"
    android:pathData="M35,35.2468C29.8084,35.2468 21.3889,38.3349 21.3889,44.4649C21.3889,44.4649 23.6574,50.5554 35,50.5554C46.3426,50.5554 48.6111,44.4649 48.6111,44.4649C48.6111,38.3349 40.1917,35.2468 35,35.2468ZM35,35.2468C39.2956,35.2468 42.7778,31.7093 42.7778,27.3456C42.7778,22.9818 39.2956,19.4443 35,19.4443C30.7045,19.4443 27.2222,22.9818 27.2222,27.3456C27.2222,31.7093 30.7045,35.2468 35,35.2468Z"
    android:strokeWidth="2"
    android:strokeColor="@color/sync_profile_stroke" />
</vector>
```

where

> ```
>     android:fillColor="@color/color_surface"
>     android:fillColor="@color/sync_profile_fill"
> ```

have 2 different references (dark/light theme)

I already created a theme for compose. Can I use the colors from the compose theme in the drawable?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file in the default Compose template called `Theme.kt`. You can create a little custom Composable for it, something like this

```
@Composable
fun getThemedColour() : Color{ //This is the Compose Color, double check while importing
 if(isSystemInDarkTheme()) return Blue else return Red
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. You answer doesn't really help me. I already have a theme with the defined colors for dark/light mode. My question was if I can somehow refer to these colors in the xml of the drawable like  android:fillColor=MatherialTheme.myTheme.myColor

Comment: No, this would not be possible. If you use the default template, without making any changes, there will be a `themes.xml`, which contains the source to default color values used in the app, like `Purple200` and others, so if you want to reference those values, you would need to explicitly declare them in something like colors.xml.

Comment: What you are essentially trying to do is trying to refer to something programmatic and dynamic from XML. Now I don't know if you know it or not, but they are just the opposites. XML is built to be static, which is the whole reason why we are shifting to the programmatic paradigm these days, that's JC

Comment: As Richard mentioned above, I found the easiest way was to create a `values-night/colors.xml` file with my dark theme colors referenced in the drawable and in my normal `values/colors.xml` I have those same variables with the light theme. The drawable will automatically assign the correct colors for you.